# I try to get data from firebase and give me this error _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety

I try to fetch data from array field, but I give the error. The error is:

> _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

I don't know where is the problem in this code.

when I deleted null check operator(!) in this line `List.from(value.data()!['totkm']).forEach((element)`, VSCode also give me error and The VSCode asks me to put a null check operator(!).

```
List<int>totkm=[];
getdata() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance 
        .collection("TotalKM")
        .doc()
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        List.from(value.data()!['totkm']).forEach((element) {
          totkm.add(int.parse(element));
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Check if `value.data()` is null, then proceed,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance 
    .collection("TotalKM")
    .doc()
```

Calling `doc()` without arguments generates a reference to a new, **non-existing** document. You then call `get()` on that reference, which gives you a snapshot for that non-existing document, so without any data. Then calling `value.data()!` is an error, as by using `!` you tell the compiler that you *know* the `data()` cannot be `null`, and that is false.

To get rid of the error most easily, use `?` instead of `!`.

But more likely, you'll need to pass the document ID of the document you want to load into the call to `doc()`: `...doc("idOfDocumentYouWantToLoad").get()...`.